# trigger an event in Ubuntu 22.04.2 when a notification is displayed

Tags: python, ubuntu, notifications, dbus

I have this code that comes from a combination of useful articles, google, chat gpt etc. The script is supposed to do something when a notification is displayed. Once the script actually works i want it to play a sound. I can do that part. However the script does nothing. I can send a notify-send "hello" . the notification displays below the time in ubuntu as you would expect but the terminal window with the script running does nothing.
I can't seem to get the script to hook into the notification event.
I've tried running the script as sudo and it still doesn't work.
Do i need to give permissions somewhere ?

many thanks

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def notifications(bus, message):
    print("something happened")
    if message.get_member() == "Notify":
        args = message.get_args_list()
        print(args)

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
proxy = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.Notifications", "/org/freedesktop/Notifications")
iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, "org.freedesktop.Notifications")
iface.connect_to_signal("NotificationClosed", notifications)
iface.connect_to_signal("ActionInvoked", notifications)

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```

Comment: this utility can hook into the messages fine so it is not a permissions based.

**dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"**

Answer (score 1):

If you look closer at your own code, you'll note that it isn't attaching any handlers to the "notification shown" signal, only to the "notification *closed*" signal.

More to the point, **there *is* no "notification shown" signal** at all – the notification daemon literally doesn't send one. There is only a "Notify" *method call* sent to the notification service (not *from* it), and method calls are not broadcast like signals; they are always directed to a specific service. You cannot receive messages that are directed to a different bus name. (And, of course, even if you *did* receive a method call, connect_to_signal() would ignore that because it's not a signal.)

The way dbus-monitor does it is by switching its bus connection to a special "monitor" mode (similar to Ethernet promisc mode in tcpdump). If you run dbus-monitor twice, you would see that it issues a `BecomeMonitor` call on the `/org/freedesktop/DBus` object:

```
‣ Type=method_call  Endian=l  Flags=0  Version=1 Cookie=2  Timestamp="Sat 2023-08-05 12:27:52.091283 UTC"
  Sender=:1.313  Destination=org.freedesktop.DBus  Path=/org/freedesktop/DBus
    Interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring  Member=BecomeMonitor
  UniqueName=:1.313
  MESSAGE "asu" {
          ARRAY "s" {
          };
          UINT32 0;
  };

‣ Type=method_return  Endian=l  Flags=1  Version=1 Cookie=3  ReplyCookie=2  Timestamp="Sat 2023-08-05 12:27:52.091345 UTC"
  Sender=org.freedesktop.DBus  Destination=:1.313
  MESSAGE "" {
  };
```

Comment: I have managed to hack a version of dbus-monitor in c to intecept the notifications i was interested in (teams messages) . However its overly techy is there any way to access the monitor mode from python or java ?

Comment: Yes, it's already mentioned in the post. You make a bus call and the connection enters monitor mode. That's how dbus-monitor itself does it...

Comment: I understand, its too hard to do in python or java. I'll stick with c.